# Page loads forever API/Fetching Data from Database

Tags: reactjs

yesterday the API was still working. It displayed the database's information as a JSON document.
However, when I wanted to continue working today and started another test query, it loaded the page indefinitely without providing any results. No error is shown in the console in VSC and in Browser.

I changed the port and also restarted the app

```
const dbapp = require('mysql');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors);
const database = dbapp.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'bws_os'
});

app.get('/v1/produktdetails', (re, res) =>{
    const sql = "Select * from produktdetails"
    database.query(sql, (err, data) =>{
        if(err) return res.json(err);
        return res.json(data);
    })
});

app.get('/v1/produktdetails/:id',(re, res) =>{
    const sql = "Select * from produktattribute WHERE ProduktID=:id"
    database.query(sql, (err, data) =>{
        if(err) return res.json(err);
        return res.json(data);
    })
});

app.listen(5137, ()=>{
    console.log('Listening');
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a problem with the way you are using `cors`. According to the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html). The package should be used as shown in below:

```
app.use(cors());
```

Sometimes if the module passed to `express` is invalid, it would just result in infinite running with no response, and no errors (yeah, I know, it’s very annoying).

P.S. I’m still in traffic, so please let me know if it does not work, so I could provide better answer when I get my computer.

Comment: @Senar Good to know it helps. Happy coding!